# How to extend a Go interface to another interface?

Tags: go, interface

I have a Go interface:

```
type People interface {
    GetName() string
    GetAge() string
}
```

Now I want another interface `Student`:

1.

```
type Student interface {
    GetName() string
    GetAge() string
    GetScore() int
    GetSchoolName() string
}
```

But I don't want to write the duplicate function `GetName` and `GetAge`.

Is there a way to avoid write `GetName` and `GetAge` in `Student` interface ? like:

2.

```
type Student interface {
    People interface
    GetScore() int
    GetSchoolName() string
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can embed interface types. See the [Interface type specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)

```
type Student interface {
    People
    GetScore() int
    GetSchoolName() string
}
```

Answer (score 36):

This is a full example about interface extend:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type People interface {
    GetName() string
    GetAge() int
}

type Student interface {
    People
    GetScore() int
    GetSchool() string
}

type StudentImpl struct {
    name string
    age int
    score int
    school string
}

func NewStudent() Student {
    var s = new(StudentImpl)
    s.name = "Jack"
    s.age = 18
    s.score = 100
    s.school = "HighSchool"
    return s
}

func (a *StudentImpl) GetName() string {
    return a.name
}

func (a *StudentImpl) GetAge() int {
    return a.age
}

func (a *StudentImpl) GetScore() int {
    return a.score
}

func (a *StudentImpl) GetSchool() string {
    return a.school
}


func main() {
    var a = NewStudent()
    fmt.Println(a.GetName())
    fmt.Println(a.GetAge())
    fmt.Println(a.GetScore())
    fmt.Println(a.GetSchool())
}
```

Comment: It helps a lot when there's a full example like the one given here.

Answer (score 2):

@linrongbin
Your example is great, yet I think the author might have had something else in mind, like below. We can extend both interface AND struct while keeping all functions working. I don't know if I'm posting some heresy here so please correct me if this is wrong in any way.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type People interface {
    GetName() string
    GetAge() int
}

type Student interface {
    People
    GetScore() int
    GetSchool() string
}

type PeopleImpl struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

type StudentImpl struct {
    PeopleImpl
    score  int
    school string
}

func NewStudent() Student {
    var s = new(StudentImpl)
    s.name = "Jack"
    s.age = 18
    s.score = 100
    s.school = "HighSchool"
    return s
}

func (a *PeopleImpl) GetName() string {
    return a.name
}

func (a *PeopleImpl) GetAge() int {
    return a.age
}

func (a *StudentImpl) GetScore() int {
    return a.score
}

func (a *StudentImpl) GetSchool() string {
    return a.school
}

func main() {
    var a = NewStudent()
    fmt.Println(a.GetName())
    fmt.Println(a.GetAge())
    fmt.Println(a.GetScore())
    fmt.Println(a.GetSchool())
}
```